# Android homescreen widget onclick works on Emulator but not always on real device

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, android-widget

I've created an homescreen widget for Android inside my Flutter project. I've done this without a package.

My WidgetProvider:

```
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.widget.RemoteViews
import androidx.work.*
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.httpGet
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit


/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 */
class SolarwindWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {

    override fun onUpdate(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetIds: IntArray) {
        val execute = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<BackgroundWorker>(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
        
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
        
        val intent = Intent(context, SolarwindWidget::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0)
        val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.solarwind_widget)

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetRoot,
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java), 0))

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.actionButton, pendingIntent)

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
    }

        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(execute);

    }


override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent)
    println("Refresh button pressed!")

    if (intent!!.extras != null) {
        val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
        val thisAppWidget = ComponentName(context!!.packageName, SolarwindWidget::class.java.name)
        val appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget)
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        }
    }
}

internal fun updateAppWidget(
    context: Context,
    appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
    appWidgetIds: IntArray
) {


    val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.solarwind_widget)

    views.setTextViewText(R.id.value_bz, "Loading...")
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.value_speed, "Loading...")
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.value_bt, "Loading...")
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.value_density, "Loading...")

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views)

    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(
        {
            //removed function cause of privacy
            

        },
        300 // value in milliseconds
    )


}

    override fun onEnabled(context: Context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);


        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
        println("On Enabled")
     

    }

    override fun onDisabled(context: Context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled

           WorkManager.getInstance(context).cancelAllWork();
            println("Disable the widget");

    }

    class BackgroundWorker(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters):
            Worker(context, workerParams) {
        private val appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        private val appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(
                ComponentName(context, SolarwindWidget::class.java))
        private val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.solarwind_widget)

        override fun doWork(): Result {
            println("doWork");
            //removed the function cause of privacy
            }
            return Result.success()
        }
    }


}
```

My use cases:

- Click on the widget to open the app
- Click on the refresh button (actionButton) to refresh the data called in the onUpdateWidget

On an emulator everything is working. However on a real device its not working, I can click what I want but the app is not working and the data is not updating (also no logging). I don't know what Im doing wrong.

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70517714/9057721