# Android App Widget On Click Not Working When App Is closed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, widget, android-widget

*Please Don't Mark This As A Duplicate I Look All Over StackOverFlow & Didn't Find A Solution*

So basically I'm trying to build a simple widget with 4 buttons on it but onRecieve is not being called when the app isn't open in the background, I looked everywhere (even the second page of google) but cant find a solution that worked.

**The Reciever Is Registered In The Manifest:**

```
<receiver android:name=".Amount.WidgetAdd" android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_add_info" />
    </receiver>
```

**My On Budget Is Set Up Like This:**

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    for (int i = 0; i<appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
        int id = appWidgetIds[i];

        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_add);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.image_joints, getPendingSelfIntent(context, JointOnClick));
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.image_bowls, getPendingSelfIntent(context, BowlOnClick));
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.image_pipe, getPendingSelfIntent(context, PipeOnClick));
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.image_more, getPendingSelfIntent(context, MoreOnClick));

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetAdd.class);
        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                420, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        c = context;
        prefs = c.getSharedPreferences("WT", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(id, remoteViews);
    }

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}
```

**And My OnReceive Looks Like This:**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        context.startForegroundService(intent);
    } else {
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    if (JointOnClick.equals(intent.getAction())){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Joint", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            AddJoint();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (BowlOnClick.equals(intent.getAction())){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Bowl", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            AddBowl();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //your onClick action is here
    }
    if (PipeOnClick.equals(intent.getAction())){
        //your onClick action is here
        Toast.makeText(context, "Pipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            AddPipe();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (MoreOnClick.equals(intent.getAction())){
        //your onClick action is here
        Toast.makeText(context, "More", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.w("WidgetAdd", "More");
    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

### Does Anyone Have Any Suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

You have to add flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` for intent.

```
intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
```

Comment: In what file do you set this?

Comment: @Roderik see question, it has one intent only